# Prove that the following function has a holomorphic Primitive.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $U$ be an open connected set. Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions converging locally uniformly to $f$. If every function $f_n$ has its own primitive on U, show that f has primitive on U.

Im wondering if the U needs to be simply connected.

Sketch of proof:
At each point $z$ in u there is a ball over which $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly. Therefore f is continuous over the ball. Also for every triangle $T$ within the ball the: $\int_Tf=lim$  $\int_T f_n = 0$ since every $f_n$ has primitive. Hence, by morera's theorem f is analytic within the ball. This implies f is analytic everywhere on U. Here is where I'm stuck.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already proved that the limit function $f$ is holomorphic in $U$. 
It remains to show that
$$
 \int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = 0
$$
for every closed path $\gamma $ in $U$, and that is true because it holds
for each $f_n$ (and the uniform convergence on the compact set $|\gamma|$).

$U$ needs not be simply connected for this conclusion.

Comment: yes but fn only converges uniformly locally

Comment: @JhonDoe: You integrate over $\gamma$. And $f_n \to f$ uniformly on (the image of) $\gamma$.

Comment: @JhonDoe: Does that answer your question? Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: oh yes thank you i was slightly confused with the conditions of the shifting of the  integral initially. Thanks